# How to force "Edit Top 200 Rows" to validate values into Not Null fields

Tags: sql, validation, ssms, sql-server-2008

When I have to import data from a tab-delimited text file, I use Edit Top 200 Rows. However, one specific field is Not Null. When that text file contains a Null for that particular field, the Edit Top 200 Rows *inserts a blank instead of Null*.

On the other hand Powerbuilder validates the data and says that it cannot insert a Null to that column.

I'd like to switch Edit Top 200 Rows in SSMS to validate as well. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Yeah :-) I've tried various Google searches.

Comment: Also, I looked through Tools - Options - SQL Server Object Explorer (Commands/Scripting) and didn't see any options there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table which has all nullable columns. This will be a temporary table and once you get all the data from text file, you can transfer it to actual table with whatever format you want (for example writing 'none' for null fields). Querying a temp table is easier than querying a text file.